# Difficulties in understanding this recursion

Tags: c++, function, recursion, return

I don't get this recursion exercise in C++. Here it is:

```
int fatt(int x){
    int s=1; // here. since 's' will always be 1 shouldn't i get 1 as an output???
    if(x>1) { s = x*fatt(x-1); }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Type a number: ";
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 0) { cout << "Error" << endl; }
    if (n <=1) { cout << "Factorial: 1" << endl; }
    else { cout << "Factorial: " << fatt(n) << endl; }
}
```

If I put `s=0` it returns me as an output always `0`, if I put 2 it doubles the result O.o I don't get how it works. I understand that `x` is always getting diminished until reaches 2 and the returns the result but everytime the function is called shouldn't 's' be given the value of 1???

Comment: "shouldn't 's' be given the value of 1???" Yes, but the next line assigns something else to `s`, so no, it does not always return 1.

Comment: When you call fatt(3), x doesn't change. The execution of fatt(3) calls fatt(2), creating a new context with another variable also named x, but different.

Comment: A visualisation of the recursion sometimes help: http://www.mrlamont.com/uploads/1/7/0/2/17021682/factorial.png

Comment: Unce you understand the code: You don't need to do if (n < 0) cout << "Error" << endl;
if (n <=1) cout << "Factorial: 1" << endl; int your main. If call fatt(0) or fatt(1) you will get 1 as result, and that's right.

Comment: Whoa thanks guys! The image actually helped me a lot! ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you call the function with the parameter value 3: It would look like this:

```
int fatt(3) {
    int s = 1;
    if (3 > 1) s = 3 * fatt(3 - 1);
    return s;
}
```

So s is the result of the calulation `3 * fatt(2)` and the result of `fatt(2)` is:

```
int fatt(2) {
    int s = 1;
    if (2 > 1) s = 2 * fatt(2 - 1);
    return s;
}
```

So s is the result of the calculations `2 * fatt(1)` and the result of `fatt(1)` is:

```
int fatt(1) {
    int s = 1;
    if (1 > 1) s = 1 * fatt(1 - 1);  // False so this is never executed.
    return s;
}
```

The result of `fatt(1)` is 1. So that is what we return to the call of `fatt(2)` which then translates to:

```
s = 2 * 1;
```

Which gives the result 2 which is then returned to the call of `fatt(3)` which then gives:

```
s = 3 * 2;
```

Which gives the result 6.

Remember that the local variable s is pushed on the stack each time the function is executed. So it is not the same variable.

If you initiated s to 2, then the first line would read: `s = 2 * 2;` and the rest of the function would give double the value in result. Since `s` is really a factor that you end up multiplying with, in your factorial:

So the sequence: `3 * 2 * 1` becomes `3 * 2 * 2`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally understood. I should have looked carefully at each step and i would have understood it ^^.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `s` is local to the given instantiation of the function `fatt`. As the function recursively calls itself, every invocation gets its own new copy of `s`. This is initialised to 1, but doesn't affect all the previous `s` instances lower down in the stack. Each one of those is then assigned to the result of the `fatt` invocation mediately after it multiplied by its local copy of `x`.

Comment: Why is 's' multiplied? I don't see any multiplication, there is an '=' before 's' ???

Comment: I edited the answer because it wasn't very clear. Each local `s` is assigned to (`s` computed by next invocation) * `x`. So the `s` being multiplied is the one from the next invocation down, i.e. the result of `fatt(x-1)`

Answer (score 0):

's' should be 1 but it gets assigned and then changes the value it holds upon the completion of a function.

Recursions can be a bit hard to understand at first but once you do, it's beautiful.

I suggest you use a pen and paper.

1) Let x = 3;

```
int fatt(3) {
    int s = 1;
    if (3 > 1) s = 3 * fatt(3 - 1);
    return s;}
```

2) In the function 3>1 = true so it gets passed on again but this time as (3-1) i.e 2

Note: function isn't done executing

3) Now x = 2

```
int fatt(2) {
    int s = 1;
    if (2 > 1) s = 2 * fatt(2 - 1);
    return s;}
```

4) Repeat step 2)  (2-1) i.e 1

5) Since x IS NOT > 1 in the 3rd function call this results in the returning of s

```
s = 1;
return s;
```

So...

Starting at the 2rd function call:

```
s = x * fatt(x-1);
s = 2 * 1;
return s;
```

Repeat this again for the first call)

```
s = x * fatt(x-1);
s = 3 * 2;
return s;
```

Think of it like a stack of functions

1st stack ------- calls stack 2 and waits

2nd stack ---------- calls stack 3 and waits

1st stack ---------- waiting

Finally...

3rd stack ---------- condition not met return

2nd stack ---------- condition done return

1st stack --------- condition done return

Hope that helps